# Need help with output of asterisks and indexes using arrays

Tags: arrays, fortran, sorting, fortran95

The output of this program on fortran 95 displays asterisks instead of digits. Also I cannot get the Experiment# to print as intended like so; Experiment 1, Experiment 2, Experiment 3 and so on. Instead it prints as follows; Experiment 1, Experiment 1, Experiment 1.

Any ideas on how I can fix this issue? Below is my program in its entirety.

Thanks for your time.

```
PROGRAM numbersgen
    IMPLICIT NONE

        !Variable declaration
        INTEGER, DIMENSION(:,:),ALLOCATABLE::numarray
        INTEGER, DIMENSION(:),ALLOCATABLE::temparray
        INTEGER:: numrolls, numexps
        INTEGER:: i=0, j=0
        REAL:: avg=0, sdv=0, variance=0, sum=0
        INTEGER:: k, min, pos, temp

        .............
        ------

        REAL, INTENT(IN):: sum
        REAL, INTENT(IN):: avg, variance, sdv

        PRINT*, " "
        PRINT*, "Sum: ",sum
        PRINT '(1X,A,F5.3)', "Average: ",avg
        PRINT '(1X,A,F5.3)', "Variance: ",variance
        PRINT '(1X,A,F5.3)', "Standard Deviation: ",sdv

        END SUBROUTINE

END PROGRAM
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `F5.3` format requires the value to be between 0 and 9.999.  If the average is more than that, or negative, it splats instead.  To find what a reasonable format specification is, temporarily change the formats to `F15.3` so you can at least see the values.

<s>I don't see why the experiment number fails to increment.</s>  Uh oh!  Is the scope of `i` from the main program used in the subroutines?!  There are no local declarations of them and `implicit none` is in effect, so I'm inclined to think this is a problem.  An easy experiment to confirm would be to change the name of `i` in the main program to something totally different, like `expidx`, and see if there are compilation errors.  (There are four places that need changing.)

Comment: When developing a program, it can be convenient to use the list-directed IO: "write (*, *)".   Then you can have no concern about whether items will fit within output fields.  When you are confident that the program is working, you can use formats to make the output look better.

Comment: I have never seen `contains` before.  I thought it was a mistranscribed comment or posting commentary.

Comment: Never seen `contains`? Then you've never used a module either, and probably never used much of the 'cool new stuff' that was introduced twenty years ago, with f90. Don't you feel you're missing out? ;)

Answer (score 3):

By putting your subroutines inside a contain statement in the program, you give them access to the data that's declared in your program.  As such, subroutines using i and j actually alter their values inside the program itself.  Don't do this!

The 'proper' way would be to put your subroutines as separate program units or in a module and use it inside the main program.

Comment: Or just declare separate loop variables in the procedures.